# Security of Orion subscriptions

Tags: fiware-orion

(Original post from FIWARE AskBot [here](https://ask.fiware.org/question/321/security-of-orion-subscriptions/))

Hello, When using GET subscription, which requires knowing subscription UID, I'm able to retrieve information of different user subscription. Is it working as designed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it works as designed.

Orion doesn't manages internally the "user" concept. However, if you can associate user to [tenant/service](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/user/multitenancy/index.html) or to [service path](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/user/service_path/index.html) (and rely in a authorization proxy managing such concepts in order to implement user permissions) you could achieve a similar functionality. In particular:

- Orion assumes that all the subscriptions belonging to the same tenant/service are isolated from any other tenant/service.
- Starting at Orion 0.26.1, you can use `Fiware-ServicePath` HTTP header in the `GET /v2/subscriptions` operation in order to filter subscriptions associated to a given service path.